# Junit in Spring Boot keeps failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

I have very simple SpringBoot Junit but it keeps failing.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest(TokenServiceImpl.class)
public class TokenTest {


    @Test
    public void getOauthToken()
    {

        System.out.println( " done test");

    }
```

my TokenServiceImpl class has

```
public class TokenServiceImpl implements TokenService{
public String  getToken() throws RuntimeException{
          return  " Token returned"  ;  
    }
```

I get the below error : -Snippet

> 2019-11-27 19:12:45.884  WARN 15864 --- [           main]
>   o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'runApplication': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'job'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'job' defined in class path resource
>   [com/mycompany/project1/batch/configurations/BatchBDREntityConfig.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'job' parameter 4;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'batchDBWriter': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'BDREntityRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.mycompany.project1.batch.repositories.BDREntityRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Field BDREntityRepository in
>   com.mycompany.project1.batch.services.BatchDBWriter required a bean of
>   type 'com.mycompany.project1.batch.repositories.BDREntityRepository'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.mycompany.project1.batch.repositories.BDREntityRepository' in
>   your configuration.
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'runApplication': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'job'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'job' defined in class path resource
>   [com/mycompany/project1/batch/configurations/BatchBDREntityConfig.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'job' parameter 4;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'batchDBWriter': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'BDREntityRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.mycompany.project1.batch.repositories.BDREntityRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'batchDBWriter': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'BDREntityRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.mycompany.project1.batch.repositories.BDREntityRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.mycompany.project1.batch.repositories.BDREntityRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

My main method has following

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.mycompany.project1"})
public class RunApplication{


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BatchController.class);

    @Autowired 
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired 
    Job job;

    /*
     * jmxBean will get loaded when this managed bean is called from RMI, and it will fire batch execution
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(RunApplication.class, args);
        logger.debug("Batch Application has been started...");
        BatchController controller =    app.getBean(BatchController.class);
        //Start batch process when application starts or restart, its optional call and can be commented out
        //as we have JMX to expose load method on demand
        //BatchController batch = new BatchController();
        controller.startBatchProessFromMain();

    }
}

@Component
public class BatchDBWriter implements ItemWriter<BDREntity> {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BatchDBWriter.class);

    @Autowired
    private BDREntityRepository bDREntityRepository;

    /*
     * this method call the JPArepository's saveAll
     * function and saves all the list of bdrEntitiesat a time.
     */
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends BDREntity> bdrEntities) throws Exception {

        bDREntityRepository.saveAll(bdrEntities);
    }
}
```

How can i fix my Junit ?

Comment: Annotate with `@Component` your class `BDREntityRepository` or delete your `@Autowired` BDREntityRepository. Either way your are not showing the right information in your question. The problem is not that your test is running incorrectly, the problem is that you have your app wrongly configured for test profile.

Comment: ...or extend @ComponsentScan to the package where BDREntityRepository resides.

Comment: BDREntityRepository  is under com.mycompany.project1 and is annotated with @Repository. SO thats not problem as i am able to run the application correctly.I am gettin this issue only when launchig Junit.Plus i am using SPRING BATCH

Comment: @FedericoPiazza obviously  app is wrongly configured for test profile otherwise i won't have asked the question

Comment: @Rahul not "obviously", your question says that your test keep failing which is not correct, your test is not failing at all... your application is not starting. The error your are showing in your question says that you are missing a bean `BDREntityRepository` for the `test` profile. It is not related to the test case you put in your question. So, this question is impossible to answer with the information you provided.  Simply read the log `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, this means that for your test profile you are missing a bean to be annotated with @Component

Comment: @Rahul btw, you have `//@SpringBootTest` commented out and you probably missed `@TestConfiguration` as well. Your question unfortunately is not clear and it's very broad to answer

Comment: why would i need @SpringBootTest .i am not doing integration test

Comment: @FedericoPiazza my application doesn't fail when i start the application.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza
i have added code for BrdRepository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `@WebMvcTest` that is a [test-slice annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests). It's specifically intended for testing the WebMvc-related components in your application and is a form of integration test.

You've said in the comments that you're not trying to integration test your application. In that case, you should not be using `@SpringBootTest` or any of the other `@…Test` annotations that are provided by Spring Boot.

Assuming that your goal is to unit test `TokenServiceImpl`, I'd expect your test class to look something like this:

```
public class TokenTest {

    private final TokenServiceImpl tokenService = new TokenServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void getOauthToken() {
        String token = this.tokenService.getToken();
        // Assertions to check the token go here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes i just want to test TokenServiceImpl .But why should i not use @WebMvcTest as it is meant to launch only those components for those which i am testing and not the entire spring context.
Moreover 'this.tokenService.getToken();' isn't this incorrect.Why would i hit the url?I thought i need to mock it

Comment: Like shown here
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template

Comment: `@WebMvcTest` is intended for testing server side components related to Spring MVC. Things like controllers. `TokenServiceImpl` doesn't appear to be an MVC-related component. You haven't shown it using `RestTemplate` so I can't really advise on what should and should not be mocked.

Comment: yes you are right . TokenServiceImpl  is just a service to OAUTH token.I used restemplate.exchange  method to make the http call.I just want to how to test services whic which rest template to make HTTP calls .They are not controllers .And mockMvc as i understand from you is used to controllers strictly i.e classes annotated with RestController and Controller

Comment: You may want to look at `@RestClientTest` and `MockRestServiceServer`.

Comment: Thanks i will have a look.